# How to change Webpy's logger to my own logger?

Tags: logging, web.py

I use example from http://webpy.org/cookbook/logging, but it's not working.

```
import sys, logging
from wsgilog import WsgiLog
import config

class Log(WsgiLog):
    def __init__(self, application):
        WsgiLog.__init__(
            self,
            application,
            logformat = '%(message)s',
            tofile = True,
            toprint = True,
            file = config.log_file,
            interval = config.log_interval,
            backups = config.log_backups
            )
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you have an error message?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
class Log(WsgiLog):
    def __init__(self, application):
        WsgiLog.__init__(
            self,
            application,
            logformat = '%(message)s',
            loglevel=logging.INFO,
            tofile = True,
            toprint = True,
            file = 'log.txt',
            interval ='s',
            backups =1
            )
```